# Load JS script after another one is loaded

Tags: javascript, html

here's my code:

```
<script src='app.js' defer></script> //very big js file
//lots of html stuff
<script> alert(1);</script>
```

The problem is, that those are loaded asynchronously. Is there a way to wait for the second script until the first one is loaded?

Comment: If order of execution is important, then you shouldn't be using `defer`.

Answer (score 5):

If you use jQuery, there is a very easy way to do this through [getScript](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) function. Just add the part of script that you need to be executed after the load and pass it as a parameter to the function.

```
$.getScript( "app.js" )
  .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
    console.log( textStatus );
    //your remaining code
  })
  .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
    //script fail warning if you want it
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Defer instructs the contents of the script tag to not execute until the page has loaded. So I would actually expect alert popup first and then app.js loaded.

Without defer the sripts should be synchronously loaded in the order you put them.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by async-await

create a JavaScript function wrapping them both.

```
const task1 = ()=>{
 // app.js content
}

const task2 = ()=>{
 // alert(1);
}

async function asyncCall(){
  await task1(); // then task2 want start until the task1 finishes
  task2();
};

asyncCall();
```

You can use async functions to execute one function after another one asynchronously

additional resources:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

you can also solve the same problem using JavaScript Promises but I prefer async-await functions. they are less painful.

Comment: I think the idea was NOT to copy the app.js content, but to refer to its source file.